# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400

Tags: java

Вчера вечером обновил систему и джаву заодно. И вуаля, маленькая самописная программка, которая год исправно работала - теперь выдает такое:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=今夜
```

Програмка использует API сайта jisho.org, онлайн словаря японского языка. Из браузера эта ссылка открывается.

Более того, ссылка не содержащая китайских/японских иероглифов, нормально срабатывают. Например http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=tonight жуются нормально без эксепшнов.

Вот код:

```
public String sendGET( String s_url )
{
    String s_res = "";

    try
    {
        //s_url = URLEncoder.encode( s_url, "UTF-8" );
        //s_url = URLDecoder.decode( s_url, "UTF-8" );
        URL url = new URL( s_url );

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
        con.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", this.USER_AGENT );

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() ) );
        String s_buf = "";

        while ( ( s_buf = in.readLine() ) != null )
        {
            s_res += s_buf;
        }

        in.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return s_res;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Версия джавы:

```
$ java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: URLEncoder.encode( s_url, "UTF-8" ); не помог?

Comment: Если раскомментить URLEncoder, то будет: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: http%3A%2F%2Fjisho.org%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fsearch%2Fwords%3Fkeyword%3D%E6%99%82`

Comment: а если только ключевое слово закодировать? `s_url += URLEncoder.encode(keyword, "UTF-8" );`

Comment: О! Так работает! Спасибо!

Comment: @Komdosh, думаю, это вполне можно в ответ написать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать `encode` только для ключевого слова

```
String s_url = "http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword="
String keyword = "今夜"
s_url += URLEncoder.encode(keyword, "UTF-8" );
```